# Install part of program with cabal like library

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have simple program written with haskell, i build it with cabal. For example i my program has next directory structure:

```
my-prog
  * Main.hs
  * my-prog.cabal
  * SomeDirWithHsFiles
    - File1.hs
    - File2.hs
```

I want that when i'll make cabal build and cabal install (maybe something else),  `SomeDirWithHsFiles` with *.hs files, installed like a normal haskell library, and then i'll use `File1.hs` and `File2.hs` modules in other programm.

How can i do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your additional files in a `library` section, like so:

```
library
    exposed-modules:     File1
                         File2

executable foo
    main-is:            Main.hs
```

See for example, [xmonad's .cabal file.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad/0.10/xmonad.cabal)